# Save an entity which has a cyclic reference with another entity in Spring Data Mongo will be failed

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have two entities with both JPA annotations and Spring Data Mongo annotations. And they reference with each other. Like `Parent` and `Child`

```
@Entity
@Document
class Parent {
    @OneToMany
    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}

@Entity
class Child {
    @ManyToOne
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

So apparently, these two entities reference with each other. With JPA, they are ok. And with Spring Data Mongo 1.8.4, the query is also ok, just has a INFO level message says that there is a cyclic reference has been detected.

But when I try to save data, Spring Data Mongo is failed. The console outputs exceptions round and round. Then finally these exceptions make the stackoverflow.

So whether it is an issue needs to be fixed. Since when query Spring Data Mongo can protect from the cyclic references but the save action cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *INFO* level message concerning the cycle provides a hint that there might be cyclic references that cannot be handled based on type information. Since it depends on the actual data used, this just points out a potential problem that might occur during mapping.

Please refer to the documentation on using [references](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references) for information on splitting your data into multiple collections and referencing them or register a [custom converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters) for your types that knows how how to deal with your types.